# can i use array-contains and array-contains-any in the same firestore query on different fields?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

im currently structuring my firestore database. i have an "events" colection where among other fields im adding the uid of the invited users in an array as well as the status of te event to know whether if it is published, unpublished, canceled or already completed. i figured that in order to query the events collection to know if a user should be able to see the event id need something like

*events.where(invitation,array-contains,currentUserUID).where(status,==,published)*

and query a second time

*events.where(invitation,array-contains,currentUserUID).where(status,==,canceled)*

this way i could display both results, but if the status field was changed to an array of only one element, i could use something like

*events.where(invitation,array-contains,currentUserUID).where(status,array-contains-any,[published,canceled])*

but im not sure if this is a query that would run, maybe im just trying to simplify the query when querying 2 times works just fine

Comment: i just realized it does matter to query only one time, if i add an .orderby(time,dec).limit(10) i would get the lates 10, this migth be all canceled, all published or anything in between. while adding .orderby(time,dec).limit(5) to each of the individual querys would get me exactly 5 of each, but not the latest 10 events that meet any of the requirements

Comment: If you're not sure if a query will run, just try it and check if there is an error.  The error will tell you if something went wrong, and what.

Answer (score 2):

just found the answer to my own question almost at the bottom of the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries),
there it says:

> You can combine *array-contains* with *in* but not with *array-contains-any*.